# cakePHP3 Pagination don't work when I filter the result

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, pagination

I have 2 Pages. One Page show all Datas and one have a filter Option. In my first page (All Datas) my Pagination work.

My second Page (filter) the Pagination don't work correctly (Cake show only the 1st page)
In both pages i send with `$this->set('filter', $this->paginate($filterQuery));`
 
The only difference from page (all data) to (filter data) is:

> All Pages: Show all Datas directly.
>
> Filter Page: Show only Data when a form was posted (Type: POST).

My filter Page show only the first 50 (Pageination Page-Limit: 50). When I skip to page 2,3,4 he show nothing.

My Question. Can't CakePHP3 Pagination work, after a form was send? Or do I miss something in CakeBook?

Answer (score 2):

Try using GET method so when you enter your filter keyword, this keyword stay in url. When you use POST, first page is displayed because data is stored in request and after any refresh data will be lost (in your case, after going to any page in pagination).